# react.js typescript problem with JSON Array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to get myself familiarized with react.js with typescript. 
I tried to declare a Array of JSON, but it gives me error saying **... is not assignable to JSON**

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
type MyProps = {
    message?: string;
};
type MyState = {
    chat_list : Array<JSON>
    count: number; // like this
};
class ChatList extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
    state: MyState = {
        count: 0,
        chat_list : [
            {
                "name":"true",
                "active" : true
            }
        ]
    };
    ...
```

*How can I resolve this?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define the shape of a chat item, [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is an actual global object with a specific shape (`JSON.stringify`, `JSON.parse` etc)

```
    interface ChatItem {
      name: string;
      active: boolean;
    }

    interface MyState {
      chat_list: Array<ChatItem>; // Or ChatItem[]
      count: number;
    }

   state: MyState = {
      count: 0,
      chat_list: [
        {
          name: 'true',
          active: true,
        },
      ],
    };
```

Comment: thanks it worked, out of curiosity just asking, instead of declaring an `interface` can I use a per-declared `class` ?? cause I already have one class alternative to `ChatItem` as `ChatListItem`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by per declared class? As in define something just for the class? The interface or type can be scoped to inside a function or file if that's what you mean

Comment: i tried to mean `pre-declared` class, I want access it from all of my classes ..

Comment: just decalare in an another file, or better way, something like declaring as props or something , new to react-typescript

Comment: yeah for shared types I recommend you have a file like types.ts and import from there, which also avoids circular dependency issues. There are also "ambient declaration files" alternatively but I think simpler to stick to that.